# Crystal error: undefined method 'member?' for Array

Tags: crystal-lang

I'm attempting to convert some Ruby code to Crystal.

One of my methods is:

```
def check_and_pop_arg(match : String, args : Array(String))
  result = args.member?(match)
  args.delete_if{|v| v == match}
  return result
end
```

The `crystal` compiler does not like the `member?` method for `Array`. It seems that `methods` is also undefined, and I cannot find the API documentation for the `Array` class in `crystal`.

1. How do I check for membership?
2. Is there a good source for API documentation that I'm just not finding?

I've tried searching the web, but even using -"crystal reports", I get far too many false positives.

Comment: There's some documentation links here which might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/crystal-lang/info

Comment: Hi Ben, have you tried going to the language's webpage for help? I'd like to know what have you tried so we know how to make it more evident so others don't stumble with the same rock. Thanks!

Comment: I did go to the language's website. I did _not_ see their link to the API there, though the link provided by @IMSoP allowed me to find it. (Thanks, @IMSoP!)

Comment: Also, the accepted answer provided by Andre has a direct link to the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you looking for is probably `includes?`.
You can find those things in the [API docs](https://crystal-lang.org/api/1.3.2), in this case [Enumerable](https://crystal-lang.org/api/1.3.2/Enumerable.html).

```
arr = ["a","b","c"]
puts arr.includes? "b"

range1 = (0..10)
puts range1.includes? 6
puts range1.includes? 13

# a possible solution using your code
def check_and_pop_arg(match : String, args : Array(String))
  result = args.includes?(match)
  if result
    args.each_index {|i| if args[i] == match; args.delete_at i end }
  end
  result
end

puts check_and_pop_arg "b", arr
puts arr
```

Output

```
% crystal run file.cr
true
true
false
true
["a", "c"]
```